# How to find objects with the most similar fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-annotate

This is the model I have defined:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    authors = models.ManyToManyField(to='Author')
    category = models.ForeignKey(to='Category')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(to='tags')

    # some other fields
```

How can I find ten books that are most similar in these three fields (authors, category, tags) to a specific object?

For example if I have the following book object:

```
Book:
  title: Harry Potter
  authors: J. K. Rowling
  category: Novel
  tags: Fantasy Fiction, Drama, Young adult fiction, Mystery, Thriller
```

I'd like to return the book object with the most matching fields of authors and category and tags to the Harry Potter book.

My question is almost like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379206/django-how-to-get-the-most-similar-record-to-multi-filter-query), but I am looking for a cleaner answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Can you define in words what you want it to do?

Comment: I edited the text. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to import Q
from django.db.models import Q

```
Book.objects.filter(Q(tags='Fantasy Fiction')|Q(tags='Young adult fiction')|Q(tags ='Mystery'),category='Novel',authors='J. K. Rowling')
```